# Google cloud authentication when logging to google stackdriver by slf4j (logback) appender

Tags: java, scala, authentication, logging, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm trying to make some logging from my scala project using logback appender from my local PC (As described here: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java#logback_appender). I've already have service account credentials on Google cloud and I even managed to send with it logs to stackdriver through nodejs app and winston.

Could someone explain me how to inject my google service account info to my scala code or logback xml appender configuration so I can send and view some logs.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to handle this case at the end? It looks like the LoggingAppender provided by the library google-cloud-logging-logback does not handle authentication through a service account.

Comment: I managed to do it by overriding the class com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingAppender and its related methods getProjectId(), getLogging() and stop(). This way I build a logging object based on credentials I get from the service account key file in the getLogging() method.

Comment: Eventually overrided the LoggingAppender class and changed some methods there....